# Passing osascript via .Net CORE gets syntax error: A unknown token can't go here

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line

The following command,

```
osascript -e 'tell app "terminal" to do script ("idevicesyslog -u UUID | tee 'ios_syslog.txt'")'
```

(where UUID is the hard-coded device id) works fine in Terminal. It opens a new window and runs the script, but when I pass it in via a .Net CORE api call I get the above syntax error.

Even just `osascript -e 'tell app "terminal" to do script ("idevicesyslog")'` fails with the same error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do shell script "..."'` and where you're using single-quotes in `'ios_syslog.txt'` you might have to escape them, e.g. `\'ios_syslog.txt\'` and I can't test because I don't have the same environment as you do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that did not help. In the end I used a workaround as shown above

Comment: The workaround should be an answer not an edit to the question (and if you need no more you could accept it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WORK AROUND:
I solved the issue by putting the above in an Applescript and calling the script from C#. Meant having to add a non .Net file to the project which can only be edited on a Mac (so far as I know). Script is:

```
on run argv
    tell application "terminal"
        activate
        do script ("idevicesyslog -u " & item of argv & " | tee '" & item 2 of argv & "'")
    end tell
end run
```

The script was called by using System.Diagnostics.Process and passing in osascript.exe and the two arguments into the ProcessStartInfo constructor.